# raster2pgsql excessive memory usage

Tags: raster, postgis, raster2pgsql

I'm attempting to upload a raster to a PostgreSQL (PostGIS) database using raster2pgsql and I have noticed that it is using an excessive amount of RAM, over 25GB worth. The file I'm trying to upload is a 32bit float GeoTIFF, 3.6GB when compressed, it's tiled with a tile size of 128x128.

This is the command I'm using:
`.\raster2pgsql.exe -s 27700 -t 128x128 -Y -e -F -c map.tif schema.table | .\psql 'pdbconnstring'`

Why is the RAM usage so high? This is an issue because the machine it will be deployed to doesn't have nearly that much RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by running "raster2pgsql | pqsl" in a cmd terminal and not powershell.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Refer to the "Notes for Windows Users" at the bottom of the page.